# Horizontally center table row

Tags: html, css

I have a table which looks like this:
[image]

What I'd like is the bottom row to be centered horizontally, so that it will look like this:
[image]

How would I go about doing this? Note that the table will be dynamic and can have an even or odd number of elements in the last row.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/czyuyt05/2/

```
<table class="dna-table">
  <tr class="dna-row">
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dna-row">
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">In</p></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

CSS

```
.dna-table {

}

.dna-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.dna-element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
 }

.symbol {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Table layouts are pretty strict. If you want to stick with `<table>` you will need to rely on putting empty `<td> ` tags inte the table per hand or per javascript. If you want a CSS-Only way of managing an unknown amount of cells per row, you might want to work with divs and display inline block like here: https://jsfiddle.net/a4vr0ksu/ (edit: wrong link)

Comment: @Julian I was able to solve it by wrapping each row in a table: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38033843/458960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by wrapping each row in a table, and setting `margin: auto` on the table:

https://jsfiddle.net/czyuyt05/4/

```
<table class="dna-table">
  <table class="dna-table">
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <table class="dna-table">
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </table>
```

CSS:

```
.dna-table {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty `td` before and after the three `tds` 
https://jsfiddle.net/czyuyt05/3/

```
<table class="dna-table">
  <tr class="dna-row">
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dna-row">
    <td></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
    <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">In</p></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Hmm..well, that works, but would prefer a CSS way to do it, especially since these tables will be generated and resized dynamically.

Comment: This also wouldn't work if I had an even number of cells in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Edited again (sorry, edited fiddle wasn't saved):

https://jsfiddle.net/egssk58w/6/

Use flexbox, no table (divs instead of the table elements) and also no rows.

```
<div class="dna-table">
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Cn</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">En</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Ps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Gr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Pr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">Rs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dna-element">
    <p class="symbol">In</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dna-table {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dna-element {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.symbol {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: That's the same answer already posted; it doesn't work when you have an even number of elements in the last row.

Comment: Yes they should be centered even if they don't line up with the row above.

Comment: I found a solution that seems to work regardless of number of columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38033843/458960

Comment: sorry, my previous edit had a wrong fiddle link - please note the update